# CSS does not Update

Tags: css

I updated my css file for example: the first is body{ background-color: green} then I updated it to background-color:red. I view file on the server and it is updated and why is it in the browser page source is still background-color:green. Can anyone help why my css is not updating. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you refreshed the page? Ctrl + F5? Are you sure you're uploading the correct file?

Comment: You likely have caching enabled, either by a host or a plugin. You'll need to flush the cache. Also, if you've edited a CSS file that is not already in a custom-built theme or a child theme, you will want to undo the change and set up a child theme to place changes there. In your child theme you can enqueue using `filemtime()` so every time you make a change a query string with file time gets appended and browsers will typically pull the latest version instead of getting stuck with the cached one.

Comment: Thanks both of you.